# How do I use a regular expression to use just one part of a line? (Java)

Tags: java, regex

In each line of the file provided, each line follows this structure:

**8 numbers then 1 comma and then 2 numbers.**

For example: 
98468631,**51**

I would like to **only** use the two digits after the comma.

Here is the program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Read {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] marks = new String[100];

    File file = new File("sd100-marks.csv");

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            try {
                String line = reader.readLine();
                String[] sp = line.split(",");
                line = sp[0];
                marks[i] = line;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Could not read!");
            }
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.println(marks[i]);
    }

  }

}
```

Basically, I am not sure what regular expression to use in the `split()` method. For now, I have "," passed in to the method, but that is not useful for what I am trying to do and simply displays all of the numbers before the comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**split** method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

The string "boo:and:foo", for example, yields the following results with these expressions:

```
Regex   Result
:   { "boo", "and", "foo" }
o   { "b", "", ":and:f" }
```

Have a try;

```
String line = "98468631,51";
String[] sp = line.split(",");
System.out.println(sp[0]);//98468631
System.out.println(sp[1]);//51
```

[Split a String Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3481828/517134)

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 2):

`Sring.split` is indeed the method to use.

```
String[] sp = line.split(",");
//sp[0] contains the first 8 digits
//sp[1] contains the part after the ",".
```

So use :

```
line = sp[1];//instead of sp[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Important note: don't use `String.split()` in a `for` loop.

It's more efficient to use `Pattern/Matcher` in situations like this.

```
String[] marks = new String[100];
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(","); // <== this
File file = new File("sd100-marks.csv");
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        marks[i] = pattern.split(reader.readLine())[1]; // we need the part after the comma i.e. index = 1
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    System.out.println(marks[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be wrong for what you are trying to do as you are getting the first part:

```
line = sp[0];
```

Try getting the second part and you should also check that there are 2 parts in `sp`:

```
if (sp.length > 1) {
    line = sp[1];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following regex can be used and the group could be extracted if you really want to use regex: ([0-9]*),([0-9]*)
Then group(2) would give you the numbers after the comma. You can refer [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) documentation for more details.